# SQL Server : find duplicates in ntext column

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, sql-server-2000

I have a table in a SQL Server 2000 database that has these columns:

```
id: Primary Key, bigint, auto increment
CustomerID: Foreign Key, int
Received_Time: bigint (epoch time of received report)
XML_Report: ntext (raw XML file. Typically ~100kb but some reports are >100MB in size)
```

There are about 750K rows and the table is about 50GB in size.

I have found that there are some duplicate reports where the `XML_Report` values are exactly the same. I am trying to get a gauge as to how many duplicates there are with the following query:

```
SELECT [XML_Report], COUNT(*) 
FROM [Reports] 
GROUP BY [XML_Report]
```

but SQL Server returns:

> The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.

Is there any way to get a count of duplicate reports?

Comment: Why are you using `ntext`?  It is quite deprecated.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It's an old database

Comment: Pre 2005, @Bijan ? Long past time for it to have been updated by now.

Comment: If you've got bigint, you're at least on 2000, if you don't have nvarchar(max), you're not on 2005 or above. If you can cast XML_Report to nvarchar(max), you could select and group by that. Not very efficient, but it would get the job done.

Comment: Convert the `NTEXT` to `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, and you should be back in business

Comment: I used something like this `select cast(a.xmlrep as nvarchar(max)) as xml_rep, count(1) as ct
from tblSOTest a
group by  cast(a.xmlrep as nvarchar(max))`

Comment: The DB is 2000 unfortunately

Comment: You might be better off adding a new `binary(64)` column for the XML_Report hash and pulling batches of rows into an application, SHA2_512 hashing them and saving back the hash. So then you can easily use this hash for duplicate detection

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky, because as you write, it's hard to work with NTEXT columns.
One way is to write a function that does the actual comparing:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_NTEXT_COMPARE] (@N1 NTEXT, @N2 NTEXT)
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    IF DATALENGTH(@N1) <> DATALENGTH(@N2)
        return(0)
    IF SUBSTRING(@N1, 1, 4000) <> SUBSTRING(@N2, 1, 4000)
        RETURN 0
    declare @x int
    set @x = 4001
    while @x <= DATALENGTH(@N1) / 2
    BEGIN
        IF SUBSTRING(@N1, @x, 4000) <> SUBSTRING(@N2, @x, 4000)
            RETURN 0
        SET @x = @x + 4000
        
    END
    
    RETURN(1)
END
```

It looks and takes substrings of the texts and compares them. Note, that the performance will be bad, but hey, that's life.

Next, you can use it to do the actual comparing:

```sql
--drop table reports
--go

create table reports (
id bigint identity
, customerid int
, received_time bigint
, xml_report ntext
)

--go
insert into reports (
    customerid
,   received_time
,   xml_report
)
select 1
, 2
, 'A'
union all
select 1
, 2
, 'B'
union all
select 1
, 2
, 'C'
union all
select 1
, 2
, 'C'
union all
select 3
, 2
, 'C'
union all
select 1
, 2
, 'C'
union all
select 1
, 2
, 'D'


--go

-- Write some long stuff...
declare @ptr varbinary(100), @txt varchar(1), @counter int, @textchar varchar(8000)
declare cr_x cursor read_only forward_only local static for
select substring(xml_report, 1, 1), textptr(xml_report)
from reports r

open cr_x
while 1 = 1

begin
    fetch next from cr_x into @txt,@ptr
    if @@fetch_status <> 0
        break
    set @counter = 0
    while @counter < 10
    begin
        set @textchar = replicate(@txt, 8000)
        updatetext reports.xml_report @ptr  null  null @textchar
        set @counter = @counter + 1
    end
end

-- change one of the Cs so it doesn't match...
select @ptr = textptr(xml_report) from reports where id = 4
updatetext reports.xml_report @ptr 13000  1 'D'
```

I created some dummy data that populates ntexts with long strings.
Finally, the actual compare method:

```sql
select MIN(r.id) as min_match, r2.id
from reports r
inner join reports r2
    ON  r2.id > r.id
    AND DATALENGTH(r2.xml_report) = DATALENGTH(r.xml_report)
where dbo.FN_NTEXT_COMPARE (r.xml_report, r2.xml_report) = 1
group by r2.id
go
```

You might be able to improve the performance by first collecting rows with same datalength into a temporary table and then do the above part separately